# An L1 function whose Fourier series converges but not to itself

Tags: fourier-analysis

Do we have an $L^1$ function whose Fourier series converges almost everywhere but not to itself?

Comment: not converging in which topology? Please be specific.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The formulation seems specific enough to me.  If the partial sums of the Fourier series converge to a function $g$ a.e., then so do the Cesaro means.  But these converge in the $L^1$-sense to the original function.  So the answer to your question is no.

Comment: You should be able to remove your own comments.  Isn't there a little x after it when you hover on it?

Comment: I wonder: is that capability (delete your own comments) only for registered users?